# PC runs much hotter on Ubuntu 12.04 vs Windows 7 - Any suggestions?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I can have 10 browser pages open, pandora playing, an IDE open, and maybe even watching Youtube videos all at the same time and my computer, on windows, will stay very cool. Actually, I only occasionally catch notice of the cooling fan kicking on.

In contrast, while on Ubuntu the cooling fan stays on 100% of the time and the laptop stays very hot. I have installed a CPU monitoring program and the levels stay relatively low. Even when there is no load and ethernet unplugged the computer runs very hot.

Any suggestions?

Win 7 - x64 Ubuntu 12.04 x64

4GB Ram Intel Core 2Duo P8700 2.53GHz

ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650

Hitachi 320GB 7200 rpm

Comment: Note that CPU isn't the only thing that can contribute to a computer heating up. It could also be the battery or the hard-drive. It would probably be helpful to include specs about those in your question.

Comment: I will edit the OP to include that information. I just thought it was interesting that on Windows my computer stays cool as ever under load, but on Ubuntu it's the opposite. And actually, I do not use a battery in my laptop for the most part. I have not taken the computer anywhere lately, so I leave it plugged in and remove the battery to preserve its capacity.

Comment: Another thing, many computers come with pre-installed drivers from the manufacturer on the primary OS, so when dual-booting with a different OS those drivers can't be used. It's possible that Ubuntu isn't interacting with the hardware the way the manufacturer intended because of a lack of the appropriate drivers.

Answer (score 1):

first, do you have hard numbers for your temperature? 
Try [lm-sensors](http://www.linux2aix.com/linux/ubuntu/monitoring-sensors-and-temperatures-in-ubuntu-12-04.html)

Consider looking into [CPU frequency scaling](http://www.askmeaboutlinux.com/?p=1971) to dial back your CPU when you are experiencing temperatures above 70C.

[Your CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/37006/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-P8700-3M-Cache-2_53-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB) will take temps in excess of 90C, but I'm sure you want to keep it will under that.